# One Signal issue with ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I added one signal plugin on my app and implemented the initiation code

```
this.OneSignal.startInit("4c848104-daba-448e-bd62-a2b64b565a87", "985484105915");
this.OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
this.OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => this.onPushReceived(data.payload));
this.OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(data => this.onPushOpened(data.notification.payload));
this.OneSignal.endInit();
```

i tested on my Huawei P8 (android 6) the splashscreen is shown but the app suddenly crashes and no subscriber is added to the projet, so i tested with another device the subscriber is added but the app still crashes

this is my ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0 browser 5.0.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.11.2
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Linux 4.15

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```